# A framework / model for regression when each input come naturally with a prior on output?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, gaussian-process

I have a physical problem in which I want to map x to y. I plan to use GPs for this regression.

The question is: if each x in my data comes with a prior on y values, how can I model this? what framework should I use and how should I approach it? Any suggestions, links, ideas are appreciated.

Note: the prior on y that comes with each x is vital to determine y. Same thing when I will be doing prediction in future, the x's will come with priors on y, and I want to use that.

EDIT: some wanted a concrete example:
It is really complicated in its original form, but here's a toy example carrying same idea, this is a table with columns x, prior on y, actual y.

x,  prior on y, actual         y

---

1     [1, 5]  2.2

2  [0.3, 0.8]  0.7

3  [2.5, 5.8] 5

Comment: can you explain more concretely what you mean by  "each x in my data comes with a prior on y values?".

Comment: @user3235916 so, for each x, I know already in what range y should be, in addition to correct y. This is vital, from my understanding of physics, I know this should be included in the model. It is like I want to condition the prediction on this extra info, or may be augment x with this extra info. Hope this explained it.

Comment: @user3235916 I added a table. Please have a look

Comment: To be clear: 1) you observe `x` and the prior on `y`, but you do not observe the actual `y`? 2) Your goal is to determine `y`? 3) There is some known (possibly complex) deterministic relation between actual `x` and actual `y`?

Comment: @MartinModrák 1) In training set, I do have both actual $y$ and the prior on it. Later in prediction, I only have $x$ plus prior on $y$ but not actual y. 2) Yes, I want y. 3) Yes, it is indeed a complex relation between x and y.

Comment: @user20160 Yes you're correct. What I really have is a contraint on output, but I just wanted to frame it probabilistically and I said it is a prior.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. Is the mapping between $y_i$ and $x_i$ deterministic? I.e. is it true that whenever $x_i = x_j$ then also $y_i = y_j$? And are the observed constraints also the same in this case? If the relationship is not deterministic, in what form is the noise?

Comment: @MartinModrák The mapping is deterministic, if measurements are perfect, but they're not, and I want to model that stochastic element (the noise). As for the observed constraints, say they're perfect for simplicity.

Comment: @JohnDeterious good, do you know anything about the noise? Do you assume it is roughly normal? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, what you want is a GP regression, but instead of the observed variables being drawn from a normal distribution around the true deterministic function, you expect them to be drawn from a truncated normal distribution. The truncation points are then taken as data.

I am not aware of any software that would fit such a model out of the box, but you can use Stan, and combine the [Latent variable GP example](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_19/stan-users-guide/fit-gp-section.html) with the [truncated data example](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/truncated-data-section.html). Note however that Gaussian processes can be tricky to fit well (see [Mike Betancourt's](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gp_part1/part1.html) case study on the subject).

If GPs turn out to be tricky, you can use splines instead (e.g. as in [this case study](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/splines_in_stan.html) ). Splines are less appealing theoretically, but in my experience are much easier to fit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, helped a lot in formalizing it. Thank you.